# Add slide animation in WPF UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf

I am learning about animations in WPF so i decided to try making slide animation using MVVM pattern by extending UserControl.

So my animation extension class looks like:

```
public class BaseControl : UserControl
{
    public PageAnimation PageLoadAnimation { get; set; } = PageAnimation.SlideAndFadeFromRight;
    public PageAnimation PageUnloadAnimation { get; set; } = PageAnimation.SlideAndFadeOutLeft;

    public double SlideSeconds { get; set; } = 0.8;

    public BaseControl()
    {
        if (this.PageLoadAnimation != PageAnimation.None)
        {
            this.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        this.Loaded += BaseBasePage_Loaded;
    }

    public async Task AnimateIn()
    {
        switch (this.PageLoadAnimation)
        {
            case PageAnimation.SlideAndFadeFromRight:
                var storyBoard = new Storyboard();
                var slideAnimation = new ThicknessAnimation
                {
                    Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(this.SlideSeconds)),
                    From = new Thickness(this.ActualHeight, 0, -this.ActualHeight, 0),
                    To = new Thickness(0),
                    DecelerationRatio = 0.9
                };

                Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(slideAnimation, new PropertyPath("Margin"));
                storyBoard.Children.Add(slideAnimation);

                storyBoard.Begin(this);

                this.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

                await Task.Delay((int)(this.SlideSeconds * 1000));

                break;
            case PageAnimation.SlideAndFadeOutLeft:
                break;
            default:
                return;
        }
    }

    private async void BaseBasePage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs ev)
    {
        await this.AnimateIn();
    }
}
```

In theory this should slide container content.

So I add 2 sub UserControl and they are extend them by BaseControl in xaml and in corresponding .cs files for example:

```
<animation:BaseControl x:Class="RawEventDataProcessor.AddEventsLogs"
               xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
               xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
               xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
               xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
               xmlns:animation="clr-namespace:RawEventDataProcessor.Animation"
               mc:Ignorable="d" 
               d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal" Width="Auto">
                <Button Content="Previous step" Margin="5" Width="150" Height="50" Command="{Binding PreviousStepCommand}"/>
                <Button Content="Next step" Margin="5" Width="150" Command="{Binding NextStepCommand}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</animation:BaseControl>
```

And:

```
public partial class AddAdditionalInfo : BaseControl
{
    public AddAdditionalInfo()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Second sub view looks the same (of course with different name)

And in my main view I have simple container

```
  <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="Auto" >
      <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding StepContext}" Content="{Binding}" />
  </StackPanel>
```

Using two buttons I change by delegate StepContext in code behind mvvm, well stepping works, but animations do not, when I use break point in AnimateIn I see it breaks.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I missing?

The fact that setting the `Visibility` property *immediately* makes the control either visible or invisible.

If you don't touch this property, you'll see the animation effect:

```
public class BaseControl : UserControl
{
    public PageAnimation PageLoadAnimation { get; set; } = PageAnimation.SlideAndFadeFromRight;
    public PageAnimation PageUnloadAnimation { get; set; } = PageAnimation.SlideAndFadeOutLeft;

    public double SlideSeconds { get; set; } = 0.8;

    public BaseControl()
    {
        this.Loaded += BaseBasePage_Loaded;
    }

    public async Task AnimateIn()
    {
        switch (this.PageLoadAnimation)
        {
            case PageAnimation.SlideAndFadeFromRight:
                var storyBoard = new Storyboard();
                var slideAnimation = new ThicknessAnimation
                {
                    Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(this.SlideSeconds)),
                    From = new Thickness(this.ActualHeight, 0, -this.ActualHeight, 0),
                    To = new Thickness(0),
                    DecelerationRatio = 0.9
                };

                Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(slideAnimation, new PropertyPath("Margin"));
                storyBoard.Children.Add(slideAnimation);

                storyBoard.Begin(this);

                await Task.Delay((int)(this.SlideSeconds * 1000));

                break;
            case PageAnimation.SlideAndFadeOutLeft:
                break;
            default:
                return;
        }
    }

    private async void BaseBasePage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs ev)
    {
        await this.AnimateIn();
    }
}
```

**Tip:** You can animate the `Opacity` property to fade in and fade out the control rather than using the `Visibility` property.